# CSS relative div after absolute div

Tags: html, css, inheritance, css-position, absolute

I've an absolute div that I can not transform in a relative div, cause otherwise the children element doesn't inherits height parameter.

```css
.tile-project-internal-box {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1070px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px #888888;
}
.tile-project-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.tile-project-img:after {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  clear: both;
}
.tile-project-internal-box .tile-project-img-horizontal-responsive {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tile-project-internal-box .tile-project-img-vertical-responsive {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tile-project-informations {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-12 tile-project-internal-box'>
  <div class='tile-project-img'>
    <img src='https://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/7174567/shutterstock_128724608.jpg' alt='$projectImageAlt' class='$imgClass'>
  </div>
  <div class='tile-project-informations'>
    <h3 class='tile-project-title'>$projectTitle</h3>
    <p class='tile-project-author'>Autore Progetto</p>
    <p class='tile-project-abstract'>$projectAbstract</p>
    <div class='tile-project-other'>
      <p class='tile-project-place-and-tag'>Roma, Italia | #Arte, #Pittura</p>
      <p>-----------------</p>
      <p class='tile-project-founding-percentage'>
        <span>45%</span>
        <br>Finanziato
      </p>
      <p class='tile-project-founding-amount'>
        <span>&euro; 1.200.000</span>
        <br>Pledged
      </p>
      <p class='tile-project-founding-days'>
        <span>$daysLeft</span>
        <br>Giorni Rimasti
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in CSS code, I'v tried also with content=' ' and clear=both.
How could I solve it?
I should have text below image and not under.
Thank you!

Comment: Please make a snippet

Comment: I've added the snippet!

Comment: Make it clear please: do you want to have responsive image and black text description on white bg below this image? What does "children element doesn't inherits height parameter"? Do you want to have text block with same height as an image? Or, may be you want to have flexible height of text block, just to fit all the containing text strings?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's really unclear what you are asking. Can you try to better describe what you are after?